# Реализация bcrypt, использование соли. Сохранение хеша в БД

Tags: c#, bcrypt

```
string pass = "password", salt = "", hash = "", pass2 = "", hash2 = "";
bool check = false;

Console.WriteLine("Test bcrypt!");
Console.WriteLine("Generate salt");

salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(SaltRevision.Revision2B);

Console.WriteLine("Password = {0}, salt = {1}", pass, salt);
Console.WriteLine("Generate hash = pass + salt");

hash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pass, salt);

Console.WriteLine("Hash = {0}", hash);

Console.WriteLine("Check verification pass");
Console.Write("Input new pass - ");
pass2 = Console.ReadLine();

hash2 = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pass2, salt);
Console.WriteLine("Salt = {0}", salt);
Console.WriteLine("Hash2 = {0}", hash2);

check = hash2 == hash ;
Console.WriteLine("Veritification end");
Console.WriteLine("Result - {0}", check);
```

Результат консоли

```
Test bcrypt!
Generate salt
Password = password, salt = $2b$10$Y/Bk/Ct0KG9pGW49AMPKqu
Generate hash = pass + salt
Hash = $2b$10$Y/Bk/Ct0KG9pGW49AMPKqu6ZXBNx2JRyzcxutpp3bMRr58Wc3gtum
Check verification pass
Input new pass - password
Salt = $2b$10$Y/Bk/Ct0KG9pGW49AMPKqu
Hash2 = $2b$10$Y/Bk/Ct0KG9pGW49AMPKqu6ZXBNx2JRyzcxutpp3bMRr58Wc3gtum
Veritification end
Result - True
```

Итак, использую BCrypt.Net.
Сперва, чтобы использовать bcrypt на проекте, создал консольное приложение для проверки. Вопросов просто куча. Прошу ответить на них, а то уже от недели по 12 часов в день криптографии голова пухнет. Прочитал много а понял мало.

1. Сохранять хеш в таком виде в базе данных или переводить в массив байт как мне советуют (ибо грех в string хранить его)?
2. Это нормальная реализация хеширования или что то не учтено(важно, код будет перенесён на ASP.Net Core 2.0)?
3. bcrypt использует Blowfish. Blowfish — криптографический алгоритм, реализующий блочное симметричное шифрование с переменной длиной ключа. То есть создается ключ как для зашифровки так и для дешифровки значения пользователя? Или bcrypt с помощью Blowfish берет пароль и 'делает' из него тот самый ключ?
4. Нужны ли блоки try/catch для ловли ошибок?

Буду признателен за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Как удобней, так и храните. От этого мало что зависит. Ну разве что если хранить как массив байт, тогда меньше места на диске занимать будет.
2. Выглядит норм.
3. Для корректного использования bcrypt ее внутреннее устройство знать не обязательно. bcrypt это хеш функция, и она необратима. Ничего невозможно расшифровать. Внутри bcrypt используется только шифрование Blowfish. Расшифровка не используется.
4. Смотрите документацию к библиотеке.

Comment: Zergatul, а если блоки try/catch реализованы в каждом методе, то мне что делать?

Comment: Реализовывать у себя чтобы ошибку не записало в хеш, я так понял.

Comment: @JuniorOne если try catch везде есть, то пусть будет. Ошибки всегда нужно где-то логгировать